# vim recover a deleted swap file

Tags: vim, file-recovery, swapfile

I deleted the swap file and lost the modifications. The *.bash file returned to its original version. Is it possible to undo delete of the swap file (i.e., recover or restore the deleted *.bash.swp file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, unless your OS has a recycle bin / trash can where deleted files go before being permanently deleted. Regardless, it's out of vim's hands.